# SQL Query to retrieve members who didn't make any payment for the past six months

Tags: sql

I have tried to create a query to retrieve members who didn't complete a payment in the past six months. I have two tables, one for the members' details and the other for payment management. I have tried the below code but it doesn't work perfectly.

```
SELECT * 
FROM tbl_members e 
LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_paymgt s on e.MemberID=s.memberID 
WHERE (((DATEDIFF(NOW(), s.paidDate)<365) 
    AND (DATEDIFF(NOW(), s.paidDate)>180))) 
    AND (e.MembershipStatus=1);
```

This code only retrieves payments completed within the past six months.

Comment: You should use a code block for your sample query.
`like this`

Comment: Move tbl_paymgt conditions from WHERE to ON to get true LEFT JOIN result.

Comment: It should be possible to check exactly the last 6 months instead of a number of days. There are good functions for that. Would be great if you tag your DBMS.

Comment: @stu The above code only retrieves members who made a payment in the past 6 months. My question is to retrieve members who didn't make a payment at least for the past 6 months and will try to notify those members.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Paraphrased; select all customers that are currently members And have no payments in the last 6 months...

Fixing your query directly, that gives...

```
SELECT
  * 
FROM
  tbl_members e 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
  tbl_paymgt s
    ON  e.MemberID=s.memberID 
    AND s.PaidDate > NOW() - INTERVAL 6 MONTH
WHERE
      e.membershipStatus = 1
  AND s.MemberID IS NULL
```

But, using NOT EXISTS() is more readable and often less costly to run.

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  tbl_members m
WHERE
  MembershipStatus = 1 
  AND
  NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
      FROM tbl_paymgt p
     WHERE p.PaidDate > NOW() - INTERVAL 6 MONTH
       AND p.MemberID = m.MemberID
  );
```

Comment: @EliasGirma Please mark answers as accepted, if they solve your question.

Comment: This approach won't capture members who have never ordered, nor members who have registered within the last 6 months

Comment: @cod3-jr Could edit your fiddle to show which eventualities you believe are not covered? Both queries here should work, unless I've misunderstood what you're describing (which is why a fiddle would help)

Comment: @cod3-jr I updated your fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/ztuZf-ef  I added my two queries, to highlight where they diverge from yours.  Mainly due to you treating "6 months" as 180 days, where as I use a difference in actual calendar months (See `member_id = 26`, who won't reach 6 months for another 3 days, based on `today = 2023-01-09`)

Comment: I used 180 days as an approximation. 

To your question, your join on the payments table will only return records for users that have ordered prior to 6mo ago, but not in the last 6mo. 

What if a member has never made a payment? Or, if they’ve made a payment, but only within the last 6mo. 

That’s why my approach captures members that have paid in the last 6mo (approx.) and excludes them from the returned result set.

Comment: @cod3-jr I think you should test that, using the fiddle I provided. Because, it does *not* do what you've described. What it does is an outer join on payments *Within* the last 6 months (not *Prior* to), and then retains only members that do Not have any such rows. Else, how does my code in my fiddle work for Any of the rows it return? In short, edit my fiddle to include the scenarios you're describing and Evidence your assertions.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using a CTE to capture the members that have made a payment in the past 6 months and then select members who are not in that CTE result set.

something like:

```
with payers as (
    select MemberID
    from tbl_paymgt
    where (DATEDIFF(NOW(), paidDate) < 180)
        
)
Select *
from tbl_members
where memberID not in (select memberID from payers)
and (MembershipStatus=1)
```

Comment: MariaDB didn't support WITH

Comment: That's strange, their documentation indicates that [CTEs are supported](https://www.mariadbtutorial.com/mariadb-basics/mariadb-cte/).
Maybe it wants a semi-colon at the end of the statement?

Could also maybe be the subquery in where clause? I haven't used MariaDB before. You should update your question to be explicit that the solution needs to work for MariaDB

Comment: Took a closer look and I had reused your active member filter, but had it on the payments table instead of the members. I just ran it using [dbFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/FxPQPXwY) and it runs just fine

Comment: You know that none of the payments rows were inserted in your fiddle? (use date format YYYY-MM-DD, do not use MM-DD-YYYY)

Comment: Thanks. I didn't notice, just quickly used dbfiddle to confirm that CTEs worked in MariaDB

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative way to use keyword `not exists` to exclude the members who completed a payment in the past six months.

```sql
SELECT *
FROM tbl_members m
WHERE MembershipStatus = 1 
  AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM tbl_paymgt p
    WHERE DATEDIFF(NOW(), p.paidDate) < 180
       AND p.MemberID = m.MemberID);
```

Comment: The op wants members that didn't make payments in the last 6 months. So, that's NOT EXISTS (ANY PAYMENT IN THE LAST 6 MONTHS), but what you have is NOT EXISTS(ANY PAYMENT OLDER THAN 6 MONTHS)

Comment: Also, using DATEDIFF() > 180 is not SARGable. To have any chance of using an index you need paidDate > now() - 180 days.